# Groups of 3 per Segment & no more than 15 rows per Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the desired output of my table. Order of the EmpID and SegmentType does not matter as long as there are no more than 3 SegmentType per Group and no more than 15 records per group.

```
    EmpID | WorkSegment | Group(What I'm trying to update)  |
    ------| ----------- | --------------------------------- |
    123   |  yard       | 1                                 |
    245   |  yard       | 1                                 |
    478   |  yard       | 1                                 |
    584   |  remote     | 1                                 |
    321   |  remote     | 1                                 |
    879   |  remote     | 1                                 |
    747   |  office     | 1                                 |
    412   |  office     | 1                                 |
    251   |  office     | 1                                 |
    755   | support     | 1                                 |
    963   | support     | 1                                 |
    369   | support     | 1                                 |
    977   | intern      | 1                                 |
    888   | intern      | 1                                 |
    552   | intern      | 1                                 |
    225   | sales       | 2                                 |
    332   | sales       | 2                                 |
    357   | sales       | 2                                 |
    753   | yard        | 2                                 |
```

Here is the code I have so far. This accomplishes the first goal  of no more than 3 WorkSegments per group but now I need to add a limit of only 15 rows per group. Any ideas?

```
--Create table of distinct SegmentType
Select  distinct SegmentType 
into    Work_DistinctSegmentTypes
from    Work_AllData

Alter   table Work_DistinctSegmentTypes
Add     RowID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL


--Procedure to update group column
DECLARE @CurrentRowID INT,
        @MaxRowID INT,
        @SegmentType varchar(50)

SET @CurrentRowID = 1
SET @MaxRowID = (Select max(rowID) from Work_DistinctSegmentTypes)


WHILE @CurrentRowID <= @MaxRowID

BEGIN
    Set @SegmentType = (Select SegmentType from Work_DistinctSegmentTypes Where RowID = @CurrentRowID)

    Update  Work_AllData  
    SET     [Group] =(RowNum - (1)) / 3 + 1  
    FROM        (SELECT EmpID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID) AS RowNum 
            FROM    Work_AllData 
            Where   SegmentType = @SegmentType) st, Work_AllData 
            Where   st.EmpID = Work_AllData.EmpID

SET @CurrentRowID = @CurrentRowID + 1 


END
```

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need have a bit more information from you to really be able to help. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It looks to me as though you need to add a Partition By statement for your Row Number, then you can state where `RowNumber <= 15`.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE can provide the grouping interval you desire.

You will need to add an identity column to your Work_AllData table if you don't already have one.

```
alter table Work_AllData
add RowID int identity(1, 1)
```

Then you can define the interval and set up the recursive CTE.

```
declare @maxGroupMembers int = 15  --max number of members per group

declare @countEmployees int
select @countEmployees = max(WAD.RowID)  --count of employees
from Work_AllData WAD

;with baseSet as (
    select 1 groupMember,
         1 RowID,
         1 [Group]

     union all

     select case
             when BS.groupMember = @maxGroupMembers  --When max number of members per group is met
                 then 1  --reset counter
             else BS.groupMember + 1  --otherwise keep counting up members in group
         end groupMember,
         BS.RowID + 1 RowID,  --cycle through employees by a increment of 1
         case
             when BS.groupMember = @maxGroupMembers  --When max number of members per group is met
                 then BS.[Group] + 1  --skip to the next group
             else BS.[Group]  --otherwise assign members to current group
         end [Group]
    from baseSet BS  --Apply against results of current CTE
    where BS.RowID < @countEmployees)  --Stop Recursion at max number of employees
update WAD
set WAD.[Group] = BS.[Group]  --Update member group 
from Work_AllData WAD
join baseSet BS
    on WAD.RowID = BS.RowID  --by employee identity column

Option (maxrecursion 200)  --must be manually set high enough to include all employees
```